# Unity. Проблема с плавностью перемещений объектов

Tags: unity3d

Есть объекты которые двигаются сверху-вниз, я их двигаю с помощью `rigidbody.velocity`.    Проблема в том, что они двигаются маленькими рывками, из-за этого спрайты этих объектов выглядят размытыми. Как это исправить? Игра 2д. Видео приложил.
Пробовал использовать интерполяцию и экстраполяцию - не особо помогает.
Ссылка на видео - https://vk.com/video?z=video174341022_456239046%2Fpl_cat_updates

Comment: функцию движения показать не хотите?

Comment: rigidbody.velocity = (Vector3.up * -1) * speed * Time.deltaTime;

Comment: Вызываю его один раз при реюзе объекта (использую пулл)

Comment: Use gravity включен?

Comment: нет, отключена эта опция

Comment: Откройте Profile посмотрите есть ли пики, и если есть с чем они связаны , это может дать какие то намеки.

Comment: Может быть, у вас в опциях стоит перерасчет физики редкий?

Comment: Егор Башинский. Это происходит редко, тяжело поймать этот баг

Comment: Александр Акимов. Например? У меня дефолтный rigidbody. Вот настройки - http://joxi.ru/J2b9owXHX3Xa8m